# How to reset JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am trying to reset an array of JLabels. There are images on the top of the labels so when i press a button the labels are supposed to be reset. I tried to do it like that

```
 for(int i=0; i<desks.length; i++)
  {
    desks[i].setText("");
    rightPanel.add(desks[i]);
  }
```

so if anyone have an idea it would be great.cheers.

Comment: *"if anyone have an idea"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: for more clarity, you could wrap one of these solutions into a method and name it `resetLabels`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is one of possible ways

```
int n = panel.getComponentCount();
if (n > 0) {
    Component[] components = panel.getComponents();
    for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
         if (components[i] instanceof JLabel) {
             JLabel label = (JLabel) components[i];
             label.setText("");
         } 
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the generic solution. Not sure if the OP really needs to do this as he/she already have the label references in a separate array

Comment: @GETah hmmm we are saw there another arrays types, then my easiest way, previously upvoted

Answer (score 6):

No need to re-add them to the panel. It should be enough to simply set the text to an empty string.

If this is not happening, make sure you are doing it on the event dispatch thread, as so:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      desks[i].setText("");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to add the labels to your content pane again to reset their text. 
Just do the following to clear up the label text:

```
 for(int i=0; i<desks.length; i++)
 {
    desks[i].setText("");
 }
```