# Random placement of JPanels in Jframe

Tags: java, swing, random

I'm a beginning Java student and I'm trying to either randomly change the position of JPanels within a JFrame or randomly change the label in the JPanel. I managed to get a grid to randomly change colors and thought I would try to make something like the changing 1s and 0s at the beginning of the Matrix movie. So far I'm unable to achieve the desired results and would like some help. In my code I have the random color changer (I know it's not what I need, but I'm assuming I need to add correct code to the Action Listener).
Here's what I have:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class MatrixGrid extends JFrame {
    final int grid = 20;
    final int pnlCnt = grid * grid;
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("WELCOME TO THE MATRIX");
    final JPanel[] panels = new JPanel[pnlCnt];
    Timer t;

    public MatrixGrid() {
        for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
            final String[] labels = new String[]{"0", "1"};
            Random rand = new Random(); 
            int index = rand.nextInt(labels.length);
            String randomTitle = labels[index];
            JLabel label = new JLabel(randomTitle, JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setForeground(Color.green);
            label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            panels[i] = new JPanel();
            panels[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            panels[i].add(label);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panels[i]);
            }
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(grid,grid));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //I know this won't do what I want, but I think this is where I need 
        //to add code to randomize the panels or labels
        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
                    Color mix = new Color(255,255,255);
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int r = random.nextInt(255);
                    int g = random.nextInt(255);
                    int b = random.nextInt(255);

                    if(mix != null) 
                    {
                        r = (r + mix.getRed()) / 2;
                        g = (g + mix.getGreen()) / 2;
                        b = (b + mix.getBlue()) / 2;
                        }
                    Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
                    panels[i].setBackground(color);
                    }
                }
            };

        t = new Timer(100, action);
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.start();
        }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MatrixGrid q = new MatrixGrid();
        }
    }
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? I've googled until my eyes are about to fall out of my head. Any help would be very much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: What **exact** feature would You like to implement?

Comment: I would like to have the 1s and 0s move randomly. I don't know if it can be done by randomizing the panel placement or by randomizing the labels. I want green 1s and 0s against a black background. When I comment out the color changer in the listener I get a static version of what I'm trying to achieve. I just don't know how to make the numbers move about.

Comment: easiest of ways is to getComponent() from container, iterate inside this array, there to test if is instanceof JPanel ..., rest of ideas looks like as correct (not correctly coded)

Comment: Could you please provide me an example or what you are talking about. And I know the coding is not the best, but I'm giving it a go. Thanks

Comment: @Spud [e.g.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9872800/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel Thank you for the example. I'm going to play with it and see if I can make it work. I have to get myself and my son off to school just now. Thank you for your help. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if i did what You want.
I changed the `for` in the constructor:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class NewClass extends JFrame {

final int grid = 20;
final int pnlCnt = grid * grid;
final JFrame frame = new JFrame("WELCOME TO THE MATRIX");
final JPanel[] panels = new JPanel[pnlCnt];
Timer t;

public NewClass() {
    for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
        final String[] labels = new String[]{"0", "1"};
        final Random rand = new Random();
        int index = rand.nextInt(labels.length);
        String randomTitle = labels[index];
        final JLabel label = new JLabel(randomTitle, JLabel.CENTER);
        Timer lblt = new Timer(00, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
               label.setText(labels[rand.nextInt(labels.length)]);
            }
        });
        lblt.setRepeats(true);
        lblt.start();
        label.setForeground(Color.green);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panels[i] = new JPanel();
        panels[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panels[i].add(label);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panels[i]);
    }
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(grid, grid));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //I know this won't do what I want, but I think this is where I need 
    //to add code to randomize the panels or labels
    ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
                Color mix = new Color(255, 255, 255);
                Random random = new Random();
                int r = random.nextInt(255);
                int g = random.nextInt(255);
                int b = random.nextInt(255);

                if (mix != null) {
                    r = (r + mix.getRed()) / 2;
                    g = (g + mix.getGreen()) / 2;
                    b = (b + mix.getBlue()) / 2;
                }
                Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
                panels[i].setBackground(color);
            }
        }
    };

    t = new Timer(00, action);
    t.setRepeats(true);
    t.start();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    NewClass q = new NewClass();
    }
}
```

Edit: I put the whole code, try to run it and see if it does what You want.

Comment: Should I replace all of the code in the public MatrixGrid() with your code. I tried that and it compiles but does nothing when I try to run it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It changes the labels from 1 to 0 randomly.

Comment: It works wonderfully!! I deleted the random color changer and now it is just what I wanted. I didn't realize the listener had to be inside the for loop in the constructor. Thank you for your help. Cheers